# Set Exponentiation: Is Y always disjoint from Y^X? 

Tags: set-theory, notation

If $y \in Y$ and $g \in Y^X$, we often write $y+g$ as shorthand for the map $x \mapsto y+ g(x)$. Similarly if $f \in Y^X$ then $f+g = x \mapsto f(x)+g(x)$. However this presupposes that we can distinguish between an element of $Y$ and an element of $Y^X$. That is, we require these sets be disjoint. Are they?

Comment: Why do you need to presuppose such a thing? Just declare that $y$ is shorthand for the constant map $X \to Y$ with value $y$, then note that if $Y$ is a monoid then $Y^X$ canonically inherits a monoid structure. None of what I've said depends on questions like whether $Y$ and $Y^X$ are disjoint (and such questions are not even meaningful in the version of set theory in my head). 

Comment: Suppose I want to write $3+g$ in order to mean the map $x \mapsto 3+g(x)$. Are you suggesting that the best solution is to redefine $3$ so that it's the constant map?

Comment: Yes. Why? Mathematicians overload symbols all the time. 

Comment: So to summarize the problem. Suppose we redefine $3$ as you're suggesting, or even better let 3' be the constant function that returns 3. We can invent a new plus symbol that applies to functions, as in $f \oplus g$. So then we can write $(3' \oplus f)(x)=3'(x)+f(x)=3+f(x)$. Now what we'd really like is to simply be able to overload the $+$ operation. So $(3'+f)(x)=3+f(x)$. However, we need $\oplus$ to have a domain that is disjoint from the original operation $+$ before we can overload $+$. This motivates the question asked.

Comment: For instance, if $f$ and $g$ are functions that returns sets, we cannot overload the union operator by writing $(f \cup g)(x) = f(x) \cup g(x)$. That's because $f$ and $g$ are sets, and so $f \cup g$ already means union of the sets $f$ and $g$. We cannot just simply endow it with a second meaning, as this would be ambiguous.

Comment: Of course, in general the sets may not be disjoint, so the problem you identify actually occurs. The fact is that $Y$ may have a function from $X$ to (some other part of) $Y$ as an element. For example, consider $Y=\text{HC}$, the set of all hereditary countable sets, and let $X=\omega$; observe in this case that  $Y^X\subset Y$, since any function from $\omega\to\text{HC}$ is itself hereditarily countable. Similar examples abound. But meanwhile, this is rarely a problem for mathematical communication, since one can resolve ambiguities in notation by explaining what is meant.

Comment: A very similar issue commonly arises when one has functions $f:\alpha\to\beta$ for ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Since every element $\gamma\in\alpha$ is also a subset $\gamma\subset\alpha$, the notation $f(\gamma)$ admits the ambibuity of the image of the point $\gamma$ under $f$ versus the pointwise image of $\gamma$ as a subset of the domain. To resolve this ambiguity, set theorists commonly use the notation $f"\gamma$ for the latter meaning. 

Comment: Qiaochu, your proposed solution about reconsidering every element of $Y$ to be a constant map from $X$ to $Y$ doesn't actually resolve the ambiguity, in the case that $Y$ itself has that map as a point. In other words, it could be that your new version of $3+g$ is still ambiguous, if the constant $3$ map is *also* in $Y$ (as it is in my example with HC). That is, are you adding $3$ to each point $g(x)$, or are you adding the constant map $3$ to each point $g(x)$? (Absurd, I know...)

Comment: Joel, since your comment answers the question, I think you should add it as an answer. :)

Comment: In my opinion this is an interesting question, and I assume not too few mathematicians in one form or another asked themselves or somebody this question at some point. However, I am also of the opinion that this is not a research-level question (in the form it is asked). Perhaps reask it on http://math.stackexchange.com . Voting to close.  

Comment: quid, I think you might be right. Is there any way of migrating the question?

Comment: @Yianni: unfortunately, it is not (yet) possible to migrate questions [it will be possible when/if MO moves to SE2.0]. So, you would have to reask it there as a new question. It could make sense to mention there and possibly here the existing question on the other site and/or integrate already obtained information via the comments here in you new question there. 

Comment: I should have written "hereditarily countable" rather than "hereditary countable". And it is fine, Yianni, that you posted my comment as an answer. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joel David Hamkins points out, the assertion is false.

"The fact is that $Y$ may have a function from $X$ to (some other part of) $Y$ as an element. For example, consider $Y=\mathrm{HC}$, the set of all hereditarily countable sets, and let $X=\omega$; observe in this case that $Y^X \subset Y$, since any function from $ω \rightarrow HC$ is itself hereditarily countable. Similar examples abound."

Comment: Joel: If $Y^X=Y$, $x \in X$ and $f \in Y$ wouldn't the sequence $f, f(x), f(x)(x), \dots$ contradict foundation?

Comment: Ramiro, yes, I had come to the same conclusion myself, and had just previously deleted my comment. 

Comment: But meanwhile, what my argument shows is that one can arrange $Y^X=Y\cup Y_0$ for any given nonempty $Y_0$, by starting with $Y_0$, and then adding all functions from $X$ to what you have so far. After $|X|^+$ iterations, you get $Y$ with $Y^X=Y\cup Y_0$. 

Comment: Joel, in your last comment, the equation should be $Y=Y_0\cup Y^X$.  That is, $Y_0$ is part of $Y$, not of $Y^X$.

Comment: Andreas, yes, that's right.